# Why the values are converted to an Array?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.5

I have this code:

```
public function saveAction(Request $request)
{
    $orders = $request->get('orders');
    $sameAddress = $request->get('same_address');

    // NaturalPerson: 1 | LegalPerson: 2
    $person_type = isset($orders['person']['nat']) ? 1 : 2;
    $register_type = isset($orders['person']['nat']) ? array("natural") : array("legal");

    $entityOrder = new Orders();
    $formOrder = $this->createForm(new OrdersType($register_type), $entityOrder);

    $formOrder->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    $errors = "";
    $is_new = false;
    if ($formOrder->isValid())
    {
        if ($person_type === 1)
        {
            // Set NaturalPerson entity
            $entityPerson = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:NaturalPerson')->findOneBy(array("ci" => $orders['person']['ci']));
            if (!$entityPerson)
            {
                $entityPerson = new NaturalPerson();
                $entityPerson->setPersonType($person_type);
                $entityPerson->setDescription($orders['person']['nat']['description']);
                $entityPerson->setContactPerson($orders['person']['nat']['contact_person']);
                $entityPerson->setIdentificationType($orders['person']['identification_type']);
                $entityPerson->setCI($orders['person']['ci']);
                $is_new = true;
            }
        }
        elseif ($person_type === 2)
        {
            // Set LegalPerson entity
            $entityPerson = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:LegalPerson')->findOneBy(array("rif" => $orders['person']['rif']));
            if (!$entityPerson)
            {
                $entityPerson = new LegalPerson();
                $entityPerson->setPersonType($person_type);
                $entityPerson->setDescription($orders['person']['leg']['description']);
                $entityPerson->setContactPerson($orders['person']['leg']['contact_person']);
                $entityPerson->setIdentificationType($orders['person']['identification_type']);
                $entityPerson->setRIF($orders['person']['rif']);
                $is_new = true;
            }
        }

        ....

        $entityOrder->setPerson($entityPerson);
        $em->persist($entityOrder);
        $em->flush();     
    }
    else
    {
        $this->get('ladybug')->log($this->getFormErrors($formOrder));
        $message = 'ERROR AL PROCESAR LOS DATOS';
        $em->getConnection()->rollback();
    }

    return $this->render('FrontendBundle:Site:process.html.twig', array('message' => $message, 'errors' => $errors));
}
```

For some reason in somewhere, that I can not find, to the entity is arriving a Array as stacktrace show in this line:

> ```
> at Orders ->setPerson (array('rif' => '5345345345', 'identification_type' => 'V', 'description' => 'uiyiyuiyuiy',
> ```
>
> 'contact_person' => 'ertertet')) 
>       in /var/www/html/tanane/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php
>   at line 438

Which is causing this issue on my application:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders::setPerson() must be an instance
>   of Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Person, array given, called in
>   /var/www/html/tanane/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 438 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/tanane/src/Tanane/FrontendBundle/Entity/Orders.php line
>   276

Can any give me any idea in where to look or find for this error?

**Running some tests**

After running some test (fill the form and send the data as any normal user would) I'm confused and don't know what else to do for fix the issue. The application have two type of forms to handle `Orders`: `Natural` and `Legal`. I test the first one `Natural` and all was fine, the form validates and the flow was completely without problems. Now if I go trough the second form the the error described above appears, why? Is the same process exactly and values are OK since `$person_type` is taking 2 and it's a `integer` so, any advice? I'm getting crazy at this point

Comment: The argument must be an instance of the `Person` class.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I added some extra info, can you point me in the right direction? I'm lost and don't know where to look

Comment: [Please observe the this link](https://eval.in/193310). I believe this will help give you some clarity.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy this is exactly what I'm doing, first create `$entityPerson` and then setting it to `$entityOrder`, what's is wrong there? In other side `$person_type` takes `2` as value but I try to `die("Enter")` in the conditional and it's not working the same error appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after having made several test finally found what was wrong, I complety forgot this function at `LegalPersonType.php` form:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\LegalPerson'
    ));
}
```

And that was causing the issue, thanks for your help and time